# Send notifications to iPad application through Mac application

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, networking

As the title states, I have to create a Mac OSX program that will have a textfield, and once the text is entered, the corresponding iPad application will have a UIPopover that will contain the aforementioned text that was entered in the Mac program.

How should I go about doing this? NSLocalNotifications?

I'm really stuck, have no idea how to go about this, and any help would be EXTREMELY appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the below two approach:

- **Using apple push notification services**: Please check [Apple Push Notification Services - Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) that has a simple php script to send notification to the iOS devices.
- **Using socket libraries**: If you just wanted to exchange data between the device & mac - I recommend [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) where you can open socket on both the devices & mac and send data to the iOS device.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will use APNS as it seems more native.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to make a network connection between the Mac and the iPad. The easiest thing to do would be to use Bonjour for discovery (the Mac and the iPad being on the same network.) Open a socket and make up your own protocol, or just use an HTTP connection (using NSURLConnection on the client side, and a simple HTTP server on the server side) to communicate whatever data you need to communicate.

Alternatively, you could bounce the message off of the internet. Set up a CGI on a web server that both devices connect to over HTTP to exchange their message.